# Keep the log for the last 14 days

Tags: shell

I'm new to Linux command. I'm currently writing a logic in **test.sh** to only keep the **Example.log** for the last 14 days.

**Example.log**

```
[2024-03-25 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-24 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-23 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-21 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-20 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-19 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-18 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-17 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-16 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-15 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-14 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-13 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-12 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-11 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
```

My first thought is to use `awk` with if to fetch each line, then use `cut` to get the first 10 characters and compare to current day. If not in 14 days, then delete it. But I'm not sure how to convert this logic to Linux command.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: linux comes with a tool `logrotate` which you can run daily from `cron` to automatically rotate and clean up log files in a flexible way.

Comment: Try your first thought. Instead of deleting a single line, consider moving everything you want to keep to a different file instead. BTW: "Linux command" is meaningless. In the different shells, you have builtin commands, other things like `awk` are programs which you call from there. Neither of those is specific to Linux though.

Comment: does your log really get created with descending order of dates?

Comment: with GNU date: `awk '$0>d' d="$(date +'[%Y-%m-%d %T' -d 'now 14 days ago')" infile >outfile` but `logrotate` or similar is much better (eg. it handles if something is currently writing to the file)

Comment: If it is guaranteed that each line in your logfile has a timestamp at the start, `awk` indeed would be an option. An alternative would be to first dynamically create an extended regex, which contains the past 14 dates as a list of alternatives, and then use `grep -E` to fetch those entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'^.|-| ' -v date=$(date +%Y%m%d) '$2$3$4 >= date-14' logfile
[2024-03-25 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-24 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-23 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-21 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-20 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-19 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-18 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-17 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-16 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
[2024-03-15 05:36:42]: ERROR No such file or directory
```

or

```
$ awk -F'^.|-| ' -v date=$(date +%Y%m%d) '$2$3$4 < date-14{exit}1' logfile
```

Comment: I would love to hear your sharing. Could you please tell me which scripts in ```$ awk -F'^.|-| ' -v date=$(date +%Y%m%d) '$2$3$4 >= date-14' logfile``` do DELETE/REMOVE actions?